# What is the purpose of the exclamation point in front of the equation with single equal sign in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found these two statements in one of the old JavaScript files.

`let expand = null, root = null;`

`if ( !(expand = $curr_section.attr("data-expand")) ) expand = "Yes";`

`if ( root = $curr_section.attr("data-root") ) { if (root == "Yes") expand = "Yes";}`

I understand that `=` sign is assigning the value to the left var. However, I'm not sure what is the purpose of the `!` in front of the block? Also, why this is used inside of the `If ()` statement?

If anyone can provide some explanation with better way of achieving the same goal please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments can be used as expressions, though it's strange and usually confusing. They evaluate to the value assigned. It'll make more sense if you move the assignment out of the `if`.

```
if ( !(expand = $curr_section.attr("data-expand")) ) expand = "Yes";
```

is equivalent to

```
expand = $curr_section.attr("data-expand")
if (!expand) expand = "Yes";
```

So, it tries to assign the `data-expand` attribute to `expand`, and if there's no attribute, it assigns `yes` to `expand` instead.

Doing the same thing for the `root` section gets you

```
root = $curr_section.attr("data-root")
if (root) { if (root == "Yes") expand = "Yes";
```

or, simplified into a single `if`:

```
root = $curr_section.attr("data-root")
if (root && root == "Yes") expand = "Yes";
```

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on this. It seems that this method is not recommended for some reason. I just wanted to make sure I understand the purpose and the way it works. Thank you.

Comment: where did you read that it is not recommended @espresso_coffee ? It is used all the time and I am yet to see some linting rules that highlight it as a warning.

Comment: @Spangle https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign These sorts of things are either confusing to read for some (as evidenced by this question) or often typos (the writer meant to use `==` or `===`), so some prefer to avoid the construction

Comment: @Spangle It was mentioned in one of the stackoverflow's questions. The same reason that @@CertaintPerformance already mentioned above. It's nice to save extra lines of code, but at the same time it can be confusing.

Comment: Personally, I think it is common enough to see in a code base, so is something js devs need to wrap their head around, but at the same time, I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: i.e const isBlah = !(something || somethingElse) && nothing;

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( !(expand = $curr_section.attr("data-expand")) )
```

this is the shortened of the following steps:

- first, assignment: `expand = $curr_section.attr("data-expand")`
- second, comparision: `if (!expand)`